# Code returns Stack overflow error in Java recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

This code is returning stack overflow error, what do I do?

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.io.*;

class myCode
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = br.readLine();

    System.out.println(printStar(Integer.parseInt(input)));
  }


    private static int printStar(int n){
    if(n > 0){
        System.out.print("\n hello");

    }
      return printStar(n-1);

  }

}
```

Comment: You need a base case for which the method will stop calling itself.

Comment: @rhowell Please can you provide a snippet?

Comment: check out the answer Mateus posted. Hopefully it makes sense, if not I can post something to explain more.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do?  What is it supposed to return?

Comment: the problem is: how does the recursion end? Otherwise it is infinite (until overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you type in the number 2.

1st call: `printStar(2)`. Prints `hello` and calls `printStar(1)`.

2nd call: `printStar(1)`. Prints `hello` and calls `printStar(0)`.

3rd call: `printStar(0)`. Doesn't print anything, because `n > 0` is false. **But**, still calls `printStar(-1)`.

Your code is calling the next step independently of the value of n. In my understanding of what you want to achieve, your recursive call should be inside the `if` block. If `n > 0` returns false, just return something else, like `-1`.

The code would look like this:

```
private static int printStar(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.print("\n hello");
        return printStar(n - 1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I have to point, though, that I'm not sure if `printStar` returning a value is a good idea. The returned value will always be the same. You can change the method to `void`. Your whole code would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = br.readLine();

    printStar(Integer.parseInt(input));
}

private static void printStar(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        System.out.print("\n hello");
        printStar(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation, since the method have to return something, what should it return them. If a nice the recursive into the if statement?

Comment: you nailed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your **printStar** function will continue forever, because you do not stop the recursive function even though **n** hits 0 or below.